# In C.S. Lewis' Narnia stories, how was "Calormen/Calormene" originally pronounced?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, pronunciation

I grew up pronouncing them "CAL-er-men" and "CAL-er-mean", but I've increasingly heard "cuh-LOR-men" for both instead, which I like better.  Did C. S. Lewis ever say which he used, or does someone (such as Douglas Gresham, his step-son) remember him pronouncing the words?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I emailed Douglas Gresham two days ago and asked him which pronunciation was correct.

> I've heard two pronunciations of "Calormen/Calormene": "CA-lor-men/CA-lor-meen" (the one I grew up using/hearing) and "cuh-LOR-men" for both (the one Focus on the Family Radio Theatre uses). Could you let me know which pronunciation Jack Lewis intended and used?

He wrote back yesterday:

> The correct pronunciation of Calormen is as the Focus on the Family Radio Drama cast pronounce it, among other things, I was the pronunciation consultant to the production and I learned the Narnian pronunciations from Jack (C.S.Lewis) himself. :-)

Comment: Okay. But how was it pronounced in the Focus on the Family Radio Drama version?

Comment: I can't find a youtube clip, but I know a couple people who own it, and have heard it consistently as "cuh-LOR-men".

Comment: And now I feel stupid because I can see that in your answer, in the email you sent Gresham. Seems like now we have the creator vs. popular problem that GIF has.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of "Calormene".

Comment: If all the FOTFRT pronunciations are correct, that means that Jadis is Jah-diss, rather than Jade-iss, which I more commonly hear. Interesting.

Comment: @echristopherson Actually, Gresham does imply that everything in the FOTF production was pronounced correctly, as he was the consultant. We can infer that Calormene was pronounced correctly, and it is pronounced the same as Calormen in that production (as my email to Gresham explains).

Comment: Why did Lewis go by "Jack"? I get why he didn't go by "Clive Staples," but why "Jack" in particular?

Comment: @MissMonicaE His dog's name was Jacksie, and was run over by a car when he was 4. He decided to take on his dog's name, and eventually shortened it to Jack as he got older.

Comment: awwwwwwwwww :,-(

Comment: Doesn't it depend on where you're from? A Calormene might pronounce "Calormen" one way, a Narnian might pronounce the word another way and an Archenlander another way again - and that's before you consider anyone from our world...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about C. S. Lewis, but [WikiNarnia](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Calormene) says:

> A **Calormene** (pronounced "KAH-luhr-meen") is any inhabitant of the Calormene Empire in the Narnian World.

It doesn't give a prononciation for "[Calormen](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Calormen)".

And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calormen) says:

> In C. S. Lewis's *Chronicles of Narnia* series of novels, **Calormen** ( /ˈkɑːlɔrmɛn/) is a large country to the southeast of Narnia. Lewis derived its name from the Latin *calor*, meaning "heat". When used as an adjective Lewis spelled the name with an 'e' at the end (e.g. a Calormene (/ˈkɑːlɔrmiːn/) soldier).

Comment: I am wondering where the writers of these wiki articles got the pronunciation from. I would pronounce them /'kælɔmɛn/ and /'kælɔmi:n/, with the first vowel as in 'calorie' (or 'cat'), and I would have expected Lewis to have done so too.