# Is there an official pronunciation of the name "Jadis" from CS Lewis?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, pronunciation

Does anyone know of an official pronunciation of the name "Jadis", for the White Witch, in CS Lewis's *The Chronicles of Narnia*?

I've heard variations on the "a" as:

1. *ā*: as in "jay" (seems common in the US)
2. *ä*: as in "yacht" (seems common outside the US)

I suppose variations on the "J" could exist as:

1. *j*: as in "jay" (I've only heard Jadis pronounced with this "J")
2. *zh*: as in "je ne sais quoi"
3. *y*: as in "Johannes"
4. *h*: as in "jalapeño"

Has Mr Lewis spoken to this, or has his estate? What about the animated film, the live-action films, and the BBC radio dramatization (and how official would these be)?

I see no offering at [WikiNarnia](http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/The_White_Witch) nor [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Witch).

I've seen suggestions that the name "Jadis" could be connected to the French *jadis* ("long ago") and the Persian *jadu* ("witch"), which could lend credence to consonant (2) and vowel (2) listed above.

Comment: I'm quite curious about this too; I've wondered the same thing. Whether the film has it right or not I haven't a clue but with the background noise I can't hear it all anyway. Quite curious if someone knows the answer! Great question.

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15469/20774) would strongly imply that the pronunciations in the Focus on the Family production of Dawn Treader are correct and accurate, making it Jah-diss (with a hard J and a hard ah like Ja-ck) rather that jay-dis.

Comment: @Valorum - "Jay-Dis" would make a great rapper name, though.  I know, I know, comments aren't meant for discussion; I just couldn't resist.

Comment: The accepted answer to another question includes correspondence with the pronunciation consultatn for the FOF series, who got his pronunciations from C. S. Lewis himself. (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15467/in-c-s-lewis-narnia-stories-how-was-calormen-calormene-originally-pronounce?rq=1)

Comment: I've always pronounced it to rhyme with TARDIS - I don't think that quite fits any of the pronunciations in your list?

Answer (score 12):

In case it helps someone, she bears the very same name - same writing at least - in the French edition of the book.

It happens that *Jadis* is a French name meaning "*a - very - long time ago*".
It basically means *ages ago* but with a very formal tone. That's a word you don't hear often. Given the context in which this character appears, I thought it was a pretty spot on name.

This particular word in French in pronunced : **ʒa.dis**

Answer (score 1):

I am crazy about this name! I myself heard it pronounced "JAY-dis" in the BBC version of *The Lion, The Witch & The Wardrobe* & "JAH-dis" in the Disney version, but I prefer the French pronunciation "Zha-DEES". It always comes out of my mouth the American way though, because that's the way I first heard it.

Comment: But is either the BBC or Disney pronunciation officially sanctioned?  Especially since they differ?